# ¿Porqué no conecta MySQL con Spring Boot?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

Tengo mi API en Spring Boot, y el sistema de base de datos actual que manejo es h2 y ahora quiero pasarla a MySQL

En mi application.properties tengo la siguiente configuración

```
    #-------- Connection with MySQL -------------------------------------------

server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/rentacar?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=create-update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

En el apartado de contraseña lo dejo vacío a pesar de que al momento de conectar con MySQL workbench es 12345 para poder entrar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si coloco la contraseña me sale en la consola al momento de correr el proyecto

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Caso contrario que si no coloco contraseña me arroja el siguiente error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'rentacar'
```

Tengo las siguientes dependencias en mi POM.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.26</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

al momento de ver las bases de datos por consola de MySQL me sale tambiën

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El Puerto en tu application.propierties está como 3307, pero el de tu MYSQL figura 3306 Podrías ser eso

Comment: Lo tengo configurado para que sea 3307, no es eso

Comment: Primero ve si tienes conexión a MySQL a través de Workbench cambiando el puerto de conexión a 3307, en la imagen dice que te estas conectando a través del puerto 3306.